# On Click not working with JS

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

The code shown here is meant to take me to the next part of checkout process however I encounter the error that billing is not defined? I've tried to put a function and call that function via the onclick but this has no effect.

The code that isn't working shall be the bottom section of the code which is the JS along with the button just above

Below is the where you can see the button and the onclick callout

```
<div class="buttons-set form-buttons btn-only" id="billing-buttons-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
    <span id="billing-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
    </span>
</div>
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
</form>
```

The JS below is not working correctly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[


    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
    if ($('onepage-guest-register-button')) {
        Event.observe($('onepage-guest-register-button'), 'click', function(event) {
            var billingRememberMe = $('co-billing-form').select('#remember-me-box');
            if (billingRememberMe.length > 0) {
                if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].hide();
                } else if ($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Joe, Refer to [`How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example#`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alex I have just updated the page, does this help?

Comment: Does `billing.save()` actually execute?

Comment: @Alex nope it comes back with the error - ReferenceError: billing is not defined[Learn More]

Comment: Post your `billing.save()` method. Also ensure that your script is at the bottom of your `<body></body>` tag so the `DOM` get's loaded first.

Comment: I fixed it because I had JQuery blocking another JQuery File and therefore it wasn't working

Comment: Cool! Feel free to answer your own question and accept it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery was blocking another jQuery file and therefore it wasn't working correctly as intended, but since removing one of jQuery files it now works :D